# QGIS -> MySQL Updates

Tags: qgis-3, mysql, update

I added a MySQL layer containing GeoData to my QGIS 3 project.
I want this layer updated every time the database updates.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can refresh it on interval.

From Layer Properties> Rendering> Refresh layer at interval (seconds)

[image]

If you were using PostgreSQL you could refresh on command:

https://kartoza.com/en/blog/using-pgnotify-to-automatically-refresh-layers-in-qgis/